# Ordered List get only subitems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```js
$(".something > ol li").each(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something">
  <ol>
    <li>Something</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Something 2</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Something 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

It will alerts Something, Something 2 and Something 3.

What I need is to alert only the directly sub-items. So I need to alert only Something and Something 3.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `$(".something > ol > li").each(...);`

Comment: @Phylogenesis you can answer that mate.

Comment: Thanks @Phylogenesis . Please add your answer below to accept it.

Comment: @MMPP Please revise the accepted answer because your HTML is invalid. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original selector was close. The selector [`A > B`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) matches the direct children of `A` that match `B` rather than traversing all descendents.

As such, the following will work for you:

```
$(".something > ol > li").each(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take only `li` [childrens](https://api.jquery.com/children/)  from `ol`. In this way you will skip other tags that are present in list.

```js
$(".something > ol").children('li').each(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something">
  <ol>
    <li>Something</li>
    <ol>
      <li>Something 2</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Something 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. An `<ol>` can't contain another `<ol>` directly. Source: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html).
You will need to nest it in a `<li>`:

```
<div class="something">
  <ol>
    <li>Something
        <ol>
          <li>Something 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

The accepted answer will not work anymore because the text for all sub elements will be returned by text().
There is a dirtry way to to get only the text from the direct child li:

```
$(".something > ol > li").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text();
  alert(text);
});
```

But I recommend a cleaner way by wrapping the text in a span:

```
<div class="something">
  <ol>
    <li><span>Something</span>
        <ol>
          <li>Something 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

And now this JS will work:

```
$(".something > ol > li > span").each(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```